# Spring transaction - Propagation.REQUIRED issue when creating temporary table in Sybase procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, sybase, spring-transactions

I have applied spring transaction on the DAO methods in my project as shown below

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public String updateUser(Integer userId, String address)
{ 
    //calling sybase procedure to update user address   
}
```

Sybase procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_user_address
        @user_id      numeric(9,0),
        @address      varchar(500)

AS
BEGIN
            UPDATE users
            SET address = @address,
            WHERE user_id = @user_id
            and user_status <> 'I'
END
go
EXEC sp_procxmode 'sp_update_user_address', 'chained'
```

The procedure executes fine updating the record in users table. But fails(record is not updated) **when we create a temporary table in the procedure** as shown below

```
//creating temporary table in procedure for some logic
CREATE TABLE #usertemp
(
   id int null,
   address varchar(500)
)
```

1) Why creating temporary table in procedure causes the transaction(update operation) to fail?.
 I resolved this issue by annotating the method with **Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED**.
 2) Why **Propagation.REQUIRED** didnt execute the procedure(having temporary table) successfully?
3) Does creating temporary table inside procedure starts implicit transaction ?

Comment: Which Sybase database (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)? When the proc fails (w/ temp table), are you getting an error and if so, what's the error? (update your question with the answers to these questions)

Comment: I am using Sybase ASE 15.7. There is no error thrown in the server log when the proc (with temp table) fails.

Comment: fwiw, the error would show up at the client (not in the ASE errorlog)

Comment: Yes I meant the application log itself. No error thrown in application/client log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details about how your proc (w/ temp table) is failing, I'm gonna guesstimate the issue ...

- after creating your proc you execute `sp_procxmode / chained`, which means the proc is expected to run in chained transaction mode (ie, the proc will be called from within a transaction)
- the proc runs ok without the #temp table
- the proc 'fails' when trying to create the #temp table; I'm guessing 'fails' means you get an error message ... something along the lines of ... "can't create #temp table inside a transaction"
- and I'm going to assume this is Sybase ASE ...

By default Sybase ASE does not allow DDL within a transaction; this includes not allowing the creation of #temp tables within a transaction.

It appears that your application may be running in chained transaction mode; which means that all database calls are always within a transaction, including the stored proc execution which attempts to create a #temp table, ie, the proc is trying to create a #temp table while inside a transaction.

And since DDL (eg, #temp table creation) is not allowed inside of a transaction, the proc execution fails (and ASE generates an error basically stating you can't create the #temp table within a transaction).

Looking over the documentation for Spring's **NOT_SUPPORTED** option, it appears (to me) that this causes the proc to be executed outside of any transactional control (eg, switches to unchained mode); with the net result being that since the proc is not inside a transaction, the #temp table can now be created.

I'm also guessing that by switching to/from **NOT_SUPPORTED** you may be breaking up a larger transaction (can't really tell from this small tidbit of your code; you'd have to look at your overall transaction model to see if this is a good thing or bad thing).

If my assumptions/guesses are correct, you'll have to (re)visit your application's transactional model with an eye towards making sure you're not issuing DDL (eg, creating a #temp table) while inside a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The issue is because Propagation.REQUIRED calls the procedure having DDL statement in transaction/chained mode. As DDL statement is not allowed within transaction, the procedure should be called outside transaction scope, hence the service/method should be annotated with Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED & procedure mode should be set to anymode.